# Approximation of an infinite sum in R

Tags: r, sum, approximation, infinity

I'm calculating the probability mass function for a count variable and the normalization term is an infinite sum of the form  ∑f(n), where the sum goes over all non-negative integers (0-infinity). I'm looking for a function in R that approximates such sum. After some research I've found that classical procedures are approximations like the Laplace method for sums or the Euler-Maclaurin sum formula, but I'm unable to find a function for that in R. The function f(n) becomes decreasing after some n and converges to 0. The function is

f(n) = exp(an + b*sqrt(n) - ln(n!)),

where a and b are some constants.

Comment: You have to provide f(n).

Comment: So there is no function which approximates this for an arbitrary f(n)? If we only know that f(n) converges to zero, as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Can you write out f(n) in your post?

Comment: I added the function.

Comment: You wrote x in place of n, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I edited it.

Comment: Be careful: e.g. sum over 1/n diverges.

Comment: The ln(n!) term is of greater order than n and sqrt(n), so this should converge. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to say that "The function f(n) becomes decreasing after some n and converges to 0" is only sufficient (thus not enough;-)

Comment: Ok, I understand what you meant, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the infinite sum of values of a function is the same as integrating this function over the same interval. You can use function `integrate()`:

```
#Define the function
f <- function(x){ 1/(x**2)}

# First check on a segment
lower = 0.5
upper = 2
sum(f(seq(lower, upper, by=0.0001)))
# [1] 15002.13

# Integrate
integrate(f, lower, upper)
# 1.5 with absolute error < 3.8e-09

# For upper boundary to be infinity:
lower = 0.5
upper = Inf
integrate(f, lower, upper)
# 2 with absolute error < 8.4e-11
```

If integration is over the integer values, you can try to approximate the upper boundary and calculate (though for some functions it might be very slow):

```
sum(f(1:(2^25)))
# [1] 1.644934

sum(f(1:(2^26))) # Check how much the value changes for even longer vector
# [1] 1.644934
```

**Added after the function definition was added to the question:**
A few notes about this specific function:

```
f(n) = exp(an + b*sqrt(n) - ln(n!))
```

There is a term `ln(n!)` in this function that R will have a very hard time to estimate, since it will need to calculate N! for a very large number.
So the best approach for this particular case is to find upper and lower boundary functions and use them for approximation.

Comment: But this only applies for very small fragments (which becomes the Riemann integral if the size of the fragments goes to 0). In my case the sum is over non-negative integers.

Comment: I see I was not clear enough and wrote non-negative numbers instead of integers, I apologize.

Comment: So what you're proposing is that I truncate the sum? As in sum only to some very high n? Just truncating would not be ok, because this is a normalization term and if I truncate, then the probabilities will sum to more than 1. Maybe I could find a continuous function as an upper bound above some n and then approximate that.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion with trancation of the sum will only approximate the sum. I do not know any packages that would perform the sum over the integers, so the approach of finding an upper and lower limits for your functions will be the best approach...

Comment: Also , you might want to correct your function definition - you use"n" in f(n), but then use x within the function.